# A second Excel Addin (Ribbon) installation appears when I open Excel, why?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ms-office, ribbon

I have made an Excel Add in (Ribbon).

When i run the .vsto and install it, i've one installation under Programs in Windows.

But, when I open my Excel program, another installation appears in the Programs-list.

Why is that and it shouldn't be like that right?

Update:
I notice in `Application` I have set `Target framework: ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile"`
and in `Publish - Prerequisites` it adds a Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile(x86 and x64), has that anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when you install the VSTO on your *development* computer. This is because when debugging the VSTO it will get installed though it won't show in the Programs & Features list. The VSTO will remain installed even after debugging is stopped. Even when performing a proper installation, remnants of the debugged VSTO will remain in the registry.

I've found the best way to work around this (though not ideal) is to manually remove the registry key at this location *before* performing a proper installation:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\[YOUR VSTO PROJECT NAME]`

Comment: Okay I'll look into as soon as I can, hopefully tomorrow. I don't have the problem on my dev comp. (The funny thing is, that I have 0 entries on Programs-list, so I might have installed it another way). The problem is on our production-server, after the .vsto install. That said, dev or prod, I'll look into it although i've havn't debugged any thing on prod. (btw, i have also tryed installed on prod. with the setup.exe fil, so maybe something went wrong.) idk.

Comment: If possible, I highly recommend removing all traces of the VSTO on prod (uninstall, remove all registry entries, and [clear the ClickOnce cache](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2011/07/fix-for-vsto-clickonce-application.html)) before reinstalling.

Answer (score 2):

Because maybe in configuration you have set the application to update itself automatically.
So after Excel startup, it tryes to auto-update.

Is it possible?

Comment: Project - Properties - Publish - Install settings - Updates (checking for updated frequently will affect startup speed)

Comment: Thx found it now. It's set on Check at interval 7 days. An most be default settings. So I guess that isn't it?

Comment: Prerequisites are verified on installation only, not at every startup. In Updates set NEVER, and try if anything changes

Comment: In Publish Options - Advanced there is another useful setting: Load on Demand. Try it!

Answer (score 2):

It is very common to find two instances of the same add-in on your Excel application in a development machine. Since you must be building that add-in code inside your IDE before publishing or making a setup project build.
 Whenever Excel starts it automatically detects the add-in manifests that are present on your computer.
Since you also installed your add-in your machine now has two locations where it finds your add-in one in your project folder and another at the location where you have installed the add-in. 
**So excel will, on its own add two add-ins because it found two add-ins,** as simple as that.

And it has nothing to do with your Publish pre-requisites and Target framework.

You can simply go to **FIlE->Options->Add-Ins->** over here in the window you'll find a Drop down with the label saying **"Manage"**, in that select **COM Add-ins** and click on '**GO**'.

Now in the window that opens, you'll find both your plug-ins listed there, you can remove the plugin that you do not want to see on your Excel app.

But, anyways the next time you build your excel add-in and start Excel it will again add that add-in automatically to your Excel app.

So it would be better not to install the add-in which you make on your machine until you want to test the installer or something like that.

Comment: It's not on my development machine, it's on the production server. :( The scary thing is that on my developer machine I have 0 instances and it works fine.

Comment: You'll be able to find the location from where the excel app is loading the addin. SO as I said in my answer go to FIlE->Options->Add-Ins-> there u'll be able to find your add in the list com add-ins and along with it there also will be the location from which it is loading.